# Failed to add account in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: users

When I tried adding user through the administrator account - ie User Accounts->unlock-> click + to add account -> account type 'standard' and after adding username and fullname when I click Add I get

```
Failed to add account 
running '/usr/sbin/adduser' failed: Child process exited with code 1'
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/677749/edit) and add the full command you have run and the full output you have got..

Answer (score 2):

i think you are using either capital letter , space or some thing different then username rule . try in lower case . use format

```
([a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30})
```

you can take help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949667/what-are-the-real-rules-for-linux-usernames-on-centos-6-and-rhel-6)
if you want to create user with capital then use bellow command to create user

```
sudo adduser --force-badname username
```

or 
you can change `/etc/adduser.conf`

```
#NAME_REGEX="^[a-z][-a-z0-9_]*\$"
```

to

```
NAME_REGEX="^[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9_]*\$"
```

you can change this  `NAME_REGEX`  according to your requirement. 
if still your problem not resolved then open terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run command

```
sudo adduser username
```

**Note :** try to keep standard naming rules some application or library  follow this rules so sometime it may introduce problem.

Comment: when I try typing the above commands in terminal window it says I need to be in

Comment: i am not getting . once you run that command then it will ask some basic password , full name etc.

Comment: Is there any limitations on adding user account

Comment: @Neena in what sense you are asking limitation . please ,  share in details.  is my answer helped you ? if yes, then you can accept answer by clicking on tick mark in left side of my answer  that will be helpful for other who face similar problem. if your problem not resolved then share what error you are getting now.